# How to create a Java-based Play Framework Application (Not Scala)

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, cloudbees, paas

Is there any way to create a Java PlayFramework application on Cloudbees?

As far as I know, it automatically creates a Scala application with STB setup on Jenkins : http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Playframework

Is there anyway to use the Java's version?

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a SBT application on Cloudbees because any Play project is an SBT project. SBT is nothing more than a build system such as Maven (kind of) and SBT is in Scala (Scala Build Tool). No worries, you can code your whole Play application in Java without problem.

Checkout the [official documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Build) for more inforrmation.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I guess I only have to change the "mainLang = SCALA" to "mainLang = JAVA" and it's gonna work.